# LEFT OUTER JOIN selects just one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to `SELECT` data from my database with the method `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but when I run my syntax the result is just one row. I am sure the result must be more rows.

I also tried the method `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. But when I do that I get an syntax error.

Does someone know why I am gettin just one row?

Here is my sql syntax:

```
SELECT
    cus.cus_id
,   cus.name_cus
,   cus.address, count(invoice.id) as id2
,   CONCAT('€ ', ROUND(SUM(invoice.total),2)) as total
,   cus.id
FROM cus
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice
ON cus.cus_id = invoice.cus_id
```

Comment: I got a syntax error too. The only difference is that I bothered to read mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using aggregate functions without `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    cus.cus_id
,   cus.name_cus
,   cus.address
,   count(invoice.id) as id2
,   CONCAT('€ ', ROUND(SUM(invoice.total),2)) as total
,   cus.id
FROM cus
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice ON cus.cus_id = invoice.cus_id
GROUP BY cus.cus_id, cus.name_cus, cus.address, cus.id
```

Although you need to group only by the unique ID (i.e. `cus.id`) you should add other fields that are not aggregated to `GROUP BY` clause as well, even though they do not create additional groups.